# How encoding ? (mysql)

Tags: mysql, encoding

I will encoding this format https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPwML.png  to this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUie1.png , how can ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HEX(info_hash)` converts letters (including accented letters) into hex strings.  I can see from the hex that your text is utf8-encoded.

If that does not answer your question, rephrase the question.